# how to get url from client request in python

Tags: python

I have written a web server in python, the client uses web-browser to send the requests like this:

```
http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp
```

On server side when I am printing the client-request it is like this:

```
GET /ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13555
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13555
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

But I only want to get & print the actual URL like:

```
Referer: http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp
```

please tell how can I do this?

Comment: The URL should be gotten **from the `GET` line**, not the Referer header on the favicon.

Comment: Why is this question an almost exact duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552358/how-to-get-integer-values-from-a-url-request)?

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular reg-ex search in result set within python:

```
import re
for line in <your results set>:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('^Referer:', line) :
        print line
```

If you don't have reg-ex:

```
for line in <your results set>:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if '^Referer:' in line) :
        print line
```

Comment: @SajalAli: ... and Python on Windows does not have regex support? News to me!